# Function to keep listening a service Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend, client

I have two component, I would one of them keep listening value of a variable set in a service. One component with:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { SearchService } from '../services/search/search.service';
    
    export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    
    @Input() queryValue: string;
    
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    
    onClearFilter() {
      this.resetFilters();
      this._searchService.SetQueryValue(undefined);
      }
    }
```

And the other one with:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from '../services/search/search.service';

export class MmSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  queryValue: string;

  constructor(
    private _searchService: SearchService,
    private _configService: ConfigService,
    )
  {
    this.defaultSearch = SearchFilter.ALL;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  listeningValue() {
   this.queryValue = this._searchService.GetQueryValue();
  }
```

I would listening Value return undefined, everytime the other service set the variable. Something to listening everytime. Is it possible?

Comment: Use `subject` or `behaviourSubject` Here is one sample tutorial link https://thinkster.io/tutorials/learn-rxjs-observables/using-behaviorsubject-for-values-that-change-over-time

Comment: Thanks, I used behaviourSubject and works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a change of value and an action to be taken based on the change in value, then the best way would be to use **Subjects.**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ft5aDAKuW5Y

https://blog.angulartraining.com/rxjs-subjects-a-tutorial-4dcce0e9637f

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what i need!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `BehaviourSubject` to your `SearchService`  and subscribe to it changes in every component that you want:

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
 private searchQuery: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

 get searchQuery$(): Observable<string> {
  return this.searchQuery.asObservable();
 }

 updateSearchQuery(query: string): void {
   this.searchQuery.next(query);
 }
}
```

and use this service in your components:

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    
  constructor(private searchService: SearchService){}

  @Input() queryValue: string;
    
  onClearFilter() {
    this.resetFilters();
    this.searchService.updateQuery(undefined);
   }
 }
```

and your second compoment:

```
  export class MmSearchComponent implements OnInit {
      queryValue$: Observable<string>;
    
      constructor(
        private searchService: SearchService,
        private _configService: ConfigService,
        ){ this.defaultSearch = SearchFilter.ALL; }
    
      listeningValue() {
       this.queryValue$ = this.searchService.searchQuery$;
      }
    }
```

Try to avoid observable subscriptions in your components if it's possible and use async pipe in a template `queryValue$ | async` instead.
Just small advice don't use underscore for service name - take a look at [Angular Code Style](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)